# how to config mails on laravel with real hosting

Tags: laravel, mail-server

I have two type of users **job_seeker** and **employer**. I have set up my `.env` file to send mail to employer when **job_seeker** submits for a job. But I get nothing.

I am using **iPage** hosting.

P.S.: It's working fine on **mailtrap**

My controller:

```
public function send_random_offer($id,$job_offer_id,Request $request){
    $job_offer=Job_offer::findOrFail($job_offer_id);
    $job_offer_title=$job_offer->offer_title;
    $email = $request->input('email');

    if(($request->hasFile('file'))){
        $cv_name=$request->file('file');
        $fileNameToStore=time() . '.'. $cv_name->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $path = Storage::putFileAs(
            'random_cv', $request->file('file'),$fileNameToStore
        );

        }

    $employer=Employer::findOrFail($id);
    Mail::to($employer->email)
    ->cc($email)
    ->queue(new send_demand_offer($path ));
    return back()->with('succes','you post succesfuly for this job bonne chance');
}
```

My .env file:

```
  MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
    MAIL_HOST=smtp.ipage.com
    MAIL_PORT=25
    MAIL_USERNAME=moussa@maroc-emplois.net
    MAIL_PASSWORD="my password"
    MAIL_ENCRYPTION=
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
    AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
    AWS_BUCKET=
```

Comment: Did you run your queue?

Comment: train_fox yes it's working on mailtrap

Comment: Check your ISP to see required port is open and you can reach ipage through port 25. You can ask your ISP or you can use telnet to check it. If laravel is sending to mailtrap then there should not be any problem with your code.